# An explicit polynomial isomorphism between the real projective line and the unit circle.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-numbers

Prove that the map $$w=\frac{\frac{1}{2}+it}{\frac{-1}{2}+it} , t\in \mathbb{R}$$ is a bijective map which maps the real axis $(-\infty,\infty)$ to the unit circle $|w|=1$

**My try**
$$w=\frac{\frac{1}{2}+it}{\frac{-1}{2}+it} $$
$$ |w|=\frac{\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}+t^2}}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}+t^2}}$$
$$ |w|=1$$
$$w=\frac{\frac{1}{2}+it}{\frac{-1}{2}+it}$$
$$t=\frac{(1+z)}{2i(z-1)} $$
So the map is onto.

For One-One,
$$Let, \ t,t'\in \mathbb{R}$$ be such that
$$\frac{\frac{1}{2}+it}{\frac{-1}{2}+it}=\frac{\frac{1}{2}+it'}{\frac{-1}{2}+it'}$$
Gives $t=t'$

Comment: It is not hitting $w=1$ since you don't give it the missing point $t=\infty$.

Comment: @user10354138 Please elaborate. I could not get you.

Comment: @user10354138 Please answer

Comment: The map you give is **not** bijective from $\Bbb R$ to $S^1$. Notice how you can't plug $1$ into your inverse function $t(w)$, because $w=1\in S^1$ is not in the range. It is, however, bijective from $\Bbb R\cup\{\infty\}$ to $S^1$ though: plugging $t=\infty$ into the formula yields $w=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $w=e^{i\theta}$, with $\theta\in(0,2\pi)$. Then

$$e^{i\theta}=\frac{2it+1}{2it-1}$$ is equivalent to

$$t=-\frac i2\frac{e^{i\theta}+1}{e^{i\theta}-1}=\frac12\cot\dfrac\theta2.$$

In the given range, the cotangent is an invertible function.

Note that the circle is not complete, as $e^{i\theta}=1$ has no image. (And as stated, the question has a negative answer.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an elementary explanation: If you define $z(t):=\frac{1}{2}+it$ you get

$$w(t):=\frac{z(t)}{-\overline{z}(t)}.$$

**Question:** "Prove that the map $w(t)$ is a bijective map which maps the real axis $(−∞,∞)$ to the unit circle $|w|=1$."

**Answer:** Hence if $w(t)=1$ it follows $z(t)=-\overline{z}(t)$.
If $z=a+ib$ and $z=-\overline{z}$ then $a=0$. Hence $w(t)=1$ is impossible and the map $w(t)$ you define is not bijective as claimed.

The map $w(t)$ is a map

$$w: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow S^1-\{1\}$$

where $S^1$ is the unit circle in $\mathbb{C}$.

It seems you get a well defined map

$$\phi: C:=\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{R}} \rightarrow S^1$$

defined as follows:

$$\phi(v:u):= \frac{\frac{1}{2}v +iu}{-\frac{1}{2}v+iu}:=\frac{z(v,u)}{-\overline{z}(v,u)}.$$

Here $C$ denotes the real projective line. This is the set of non-zero vectors $(v,u)\in V:=\mathbb{R}^2$ modulo the well known equivalence relation: Two vectors $a,b\in V$ are equivalent iff there is a non-zero real number $\lambda$ with $\lambda a =b$.

You may check that if $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}-0$ it follows

$$\phi(\lambda v: \lambda u)=\phi(v:u)$$
hence the map $\phi$ seems to be well defined. When you restrict $\phi$ to the open set $D(v)\cong \mathbb{R}$ (the set of $(v:u)$ with $v\neq0$) you recover the map $w(t)$. Here you view the set of real numbers as a subset of the real projective line $C$ via the map

$$s: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow D(v) \subseteq C$$

defined by

$$s(t):=(1:t) \in D(v).$$

Hence you get an equality

$$ w(t)=\phi(s(t))$$

for all real numbers $t$. The inverse image $\phi^{-1}(1)$ is the set of
elements $(v:u)\in C$ with

$$ z(v,u)=-\overline{z}(v,u)$$

which is iff $v=0$. Hence $\phi^{-1}(1)\cong (0:a)\in C.$

**Question:** "Is the map a map from the real line to the unit circle? If no then how can one redefine the map so that it gives the unit circle?"

**Answer:** Hence $\phi^{-1}(1) \cong \{(0:1)\}:=\infty \in C$. Hence the map $\phi$ equals your map on $D(v)$ and $\phi(0:1)=1\in S^1$. Hence we have defined an isomorphism of algebraic varieties/real algebraic manifolds

$$\phi: \mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{R}} \cong S^1.$$

If you want to "redefine the map" map you must embed the real line as an open subset of the real projective line. Then the map $w(t)$ extends to an isomorphism of real algebraic manifolds between $C$ and $S^1$.

**Example.** Let $G:=\mathbb{Z}$ and define the left action

$$\sigma: G \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$

by

$$\sigma(k,x):=x+ 2k\pi.$$

Define the map

$$w: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow S^1.$$

by

$$w(x):=cos(x)+isin(x):=e^{ix}\in S^1.$$

It follows $w(\sigma(k,x))=w(x+2k\pi )=w(x)$ hence you get a well defined map

$$\overline{w}: \mathbb{R}/G \cong S^1.$$

The map $\overline{w}$ is an "isomorphism": You have realized $S^1$ as the quotient of $\mathbb{R}$ by the group $G$. This is the map mentioned in the other post. It factors through the quotient $\mathbb{R}/G$.

Comment: Is the Map from Real line to unit circle? If no then How can one redefine the map so that it gives unit circle?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you redefine the map without using extended real line?

Comment: Please redefine the map without using extended real line . I will give you a Check Mark